# prompt: how to know user canceled or submitted empty value

Tags: javascript

there are three stages of prompt:

1. PRESSED Ok with value
2. PRESSED Ok with empty value
3. PRESSED Cancel

how to determine between 2 and 3?

## Update

that is example

```
if(edit !== "") 
    alert("text"); // Ok with value
else if(edit === "")
    alert("empty"); // Ok with empty value, AND cancel
else if(edit === null)
    alert("null"); // ...?
```

## UPDATE 2

seems it works good in chrome and other browsers. but Not in safari where 2&3 is the same. submitting empty input it is as cancelling.

Comment: Your question is about a `prompt()`, but your sample code shows `alert()`?

Comment: edit is the `prompt()` alert to just show the respond

Answer (score 1):

1. Check for non-empty string (`result`)
2. Check for empty string (`result === ""`)
3. Check for `null` (`result === null`)

It's important to understand that a `propmt()` is part of the browser's functionality. It's not defined by the JavaScript/ECMAScript standard and so, the implementation details for them are subject to vary from browser to browser. Generally, if <kbd>CANCEL</kbd> is pressed, it doesn't matter what may have been typed into the `propmt()`, `null` will be returned.

```js
var response = prompt("What is your name?");

// You should always call the string.trim() method on user input which will
// remove any leading or trailing spaces from the string. This prevents strings
// that are nothing but spaces or valid answers that have spaces around them.
if(typeof response === "string"){
  response = response.trim();
}

// The first test tests for "truthy" values (anything that is not:
// 0, null, undefined or false. So any typed characters mean truthy.
if(response) {
    alert("You typed something: " + response);                                   // Ok with value
} else if(response === ""){
    alert("You clicked OK but didn't type anything or just typed spaces"); // Ok with empty value, AND cancel
} else if(response === null){
    alert("You hit Cancel");                          // Cancel was hit
}
```

Comment: @AbdullahSalma See updated answer. Run it 3 times, trying each scenario.

Answer (score 0):

[Window.prompt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt)

> result is a string containing the text entered by the user, or null.

```js
let result = window.prompt("Meow?");
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score -1):

There's a note here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt that says in Safari cancel will return as an empty string and is indistinguishable.

In Chrome, the variable is set to null on cancel,  and empty string when the user clicks okay.

Comment: The best option is to build your own / use a separate pop up that doesn't have that limitation,  that way you can handle each case unambiguously.

Comment: @gvfordo Safari v 10.1 seems to set null on cancel... the link you have posted in your answer is a year old and so hasn't been updated with the new safari behavior

Comment: @JarodMoser MDN is a wiki,  I don't have Safari to test with but if that's the case help the world out and update the page :)